# Swift - Inject block in property after instantiated

Tags: objective-c, swift

**revised my question

I had encountered difficulties while migrating Objective-c to Swift. As title, how do I inject block in property after the creation of its classes. Below is how I done for Objective-C. But just how to make it happen in Swift?

Header:

```
@property (strong) void(^thisMethod)( ObjectA* a, ObjectB* b, ObjectC* c );
```

Body:

```
ThisClass *thisClass = (ThisClass*) thisClass;

thisClass.thisMethod = ^(ObjectA* a, ObjectB* b, ObjectC* c) {
    //method goes here
};
```

Not sure if this question sounds stupid but your helps is highly appreciated. Many Thanks! :)

Comment: That is not a method, it's a property that holds a block.

Comment: Yes, and in Swift you'd translate it into a property that holds a closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not overriding a method after the creation of its classes. You're just storing a block in a property. In Swift you'd use a closure. This works in a Playground:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

class ObjectA {}
class ObjectB {}
class ObjectC {}

class ThisClass {
    var thisClosure: ((a: ObjectA, b: ObjectB, c: ObjectC) -> Void)?
}

var thisClass = ThisClass()
thisClass.thisClosure = {
    a, b, c in
    // Method goes here
}
```

Note that I've declared the `thisClosure` property as optional, so that it can be nil; that saves me having to make too much difference with your original code by having to set up the property in an initialiser. Note also that in Swift you don't need to spell out the parameter types when you define the closure itself (the line `a, b, c in` doesn't have types) because Swift can work out the parameter types from the property declaration.

Comment: Apologize for my limited knowledge over both language. Your method working great. Cheers!!